# can't get old documents when I update mongoengine from 0.8.6 to 0.9.0

Tags: mongodb, flask, mongoengine

I was using mongodb with mongoengine 0.8.6 and flask for web framework 
when I update my mongoengine to 0.9.0 I can't get old documents in database but when I create a new `Document` I have no problem to get it ! 
the error that raised is :

```
raise FieldDoesNotExist(msg)
FieldDoesNotExist: The field 'notification_actions' does not exist on the document 'User'
```

and when I delete the field that mentioned above for example in this case `notification_actions` it raised this error with another `field` and the thing that make me surprised is the new `Document` that I create have the same `field`s !

the class definition:

```
class User(Document):
    stores = EmbeddedDocumentListField(UserStore)
    password = StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    email = StringField(max_length=255, required=True)
    forget_password_key = StringField()
    mail_verify_key = StringField()
    firstName = StringField(max_length=45)
    lastName = StringField(max_length=45)
    marital = StringField(max_length=1)
    address = StringField()
    state = StringField()
    city = StringField()
    postal = IntField()
    websites = ListField(StringField(max_length=65))
    sex = StringField(max_length=1)
    interest = StringField()
    birthday = DateTimeField()
    skills = StringField()
    phone = StringField()
    cellphone = StringField()
    fax = StringField()
    avatar = StringField()
    msg = IntField(default=0)
    group = StringField()
    created_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now, required=True)
```

the `Document` that I try to get it but mongoengine raise error :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55c74ba4e3615342fd0b541c"),
    "_keywords" : [],
    "address" : "",
    "banks" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "55518df6123dbb06402f0e0b",
            "bank_name" : "mellat",
            "account_num" : "603799112344011",
            "card_num" : "223333"
        }
    ],
    "categories" : [],
    "cellphone" : "",
    "city" : "13",
    "created_at" : ISODate("2015-04-01T01:03:18.140Z"),
    "deliveries" : [],
    "delivery" : {
        "courier" : true,
        "post_custom_made" : true,
        "post_leading" : true,
        "free_for_price" : 0,
        "area_support" : "",
        "price_for_area_selected" : 0
    },
    "description" : "",
    "domain" : "ehsanco",
    "domains" : [ 
        {
            "domain" : "ehsanco.bab.ir",
            "is_active" : true,
            "can_delete" : false,
            "is_default" : true
        }, 
        {
            "domain" : "ielecom.org",
            "is_active" : false,
            "can_delete" : true,
            "is_default" : false
        }
    ],
    "email" : "emahmoudi98@gmail.com",
    "external_domains" : [ 
        {
            "domain" : "ielecom.org",
            "is_active" : false,
            "must_buy" : false
        }
    ],
    "fax" : "",
    "inventories" : [ 
        {
            "store" : ObjectId("551b048e123dbb0524c04983")
        }
    ],
    "is_dealer" : false,
    "logo" : "download",
    "marketplace" : "bab.ir",
    "menu" : [ 
        ObjectId("55b60037123dbb4e200560f6")
    ],
    "msg" : 0.0000000000000000,
    "notification_actions" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "buy",
            "has_email" : true,
            "has_sms" : false,
            "has_site_alert" : true
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "comment",
            "has_email" : true,
            "has_sms" : false,
            "has_site_alert" : true
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "pay",
            "has_email" : true,
            "has_sms" : false,
            "has_site_alert" : true
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "contact",
            "has_email" : true,
            "has_sms" : false,
            "has_site_alert" : true
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "out_of_stock",
            "has_email" : true,
            "has_sms" : false,
            "has_site_alert" : true
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "new_user",
            "has_email" : true,
            "has_sms" : false,
            "has_site_alert" : true
        }
    ],
    "password" : "pbkdf2:sha1:1000$1bca0pNG$b3d7085bf5090057af6fa79e617a5830ac72793e",
    "pay_way" : [],
    "payment" : {
        "zarinpal_is_active" : true,
        "cart_to_card_is_active" : true,
        "coordinatad_is_active" : true
    },
    "phone" : "",
    "related_store" : [],
    "state" : "8",
    "store" : ObjectId("551b048e123dbb0524c04983"),
    "store_name" : "ehsanco",
    "stores" : null,
    "theme" : ObjectId("55850cb7123dbb7c6e1590a6"),
    "theme_history" : [ 
        ObjectId("55094c6a123dbb2e1c280c0b"), 
        ObjectId("55094c6a123dbb2e1c280c0c"), 
        ObjectId("55850cb7123dbb7c6e1590a6")
    ],
    "websites" : [],
    "zarinpal" : {
        "zarinpal_id" : "zp.118902",
        "valet_id" : 1
    }
}
```

and the `Document` that I can get it from mongoengine:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55c74ba4e3615342fd0b5425"),
    "banks" : [],
    "categories" : [],
    "created_at" : ISODate("2015-07-01T08:55:43.052Z"),
    "devices" : [],
    "domains" : [ 
        {
            "domain" : "khallaghi.bab.ir",
            "is_active" : true,
            "can_delete" : false,
            "is_default" : true
        }
    ],
    "email" : "mdkhallaghi@gmail.com",
    "freeze" : false,
    "inventories" : [ 
        {
            "store" : ObjectId("55936bc7123dbb512c534206")
        }
    ],
    "is_dealer" : false,
    "keywords" : [],
    "marketplace" : "bab.ir",
    "menu" : [],
    "msg" : 0.0000000000000000,
    "notification_actions" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "comment",
            "has_email" : true,
            "has_sms" : false,
            "has_site_alert" : true
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "buy",
            "has_email" : true,
            "has_sms" : false,
            "has_site_alert" : true
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "new_user",
            "has_email" : true,
            "has_sms" : false,
            "has_site_alert" : true
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "pay",
            "has_email" : true,
            "has_sms" : false,
            "has_site_alert" : true
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "contact",
            "has_email" : true,
            "has_sms" : false,
            "has_site_alert" : true
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "out_of_stack",
            "has_email" : true,
            "has_sms" : false,
            "has_site_alert" : true
        }
    ],
    "ordering_freeze" : false,
    "password" : "pbkdf2:sha1:1000$99sS9KCg$572b4c418fe0f7cd6b2d0e303f622353aae0a6a0",
    "pay_way" : [],
    "redirect_all_domain_to_default" : true,
    "related_store" : [],
    "store" : ObjectId("55936bc7123dbb512c534206"),
    "store_name" : "khallaghi",
    "stores" : null,
    "tax" : 0.0000000000000000,
    "theme" : ObjectId("55850cb7123dbb7c6e15909e"),
    "theme_history" : [],
    "websites" : []
}
```

the query that I written :

```
tmp = User.objects(email=email).count()
users = User.objects(
    email=email
    ).first()
```

and the funny thing is that the first query is running correctly but the second raises an error

the full error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 859, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 732, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 471, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 331, in getMessage
    msg = str(self.msg)
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/queryset.py", line 58, in __repr__
    self._populate_cache()
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/queryset.py", line 93, in _populate_cache
    self._result_cache.append(self.next())
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 1359, in next
    _auto_dereference=self._auto_dereference, only_fields=self.only_fields)
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/base/document.py", line 709, in _from_son
    obj = cls(__auto_convert=False, _created=created, __only_fields=only_fields, **data)
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/base/document.py", line 81, in __init__
    raise FieldDoesNotExist(msg)
FieldDoesNotExist: The field 'domain' does not exist on the document 'User'
Logged from file extended_logging.py, line 113
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Sep/2015 15:24:53] "POST /store/login/ HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/project/utils/auth.py", line 53, in decorated_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/project/utils/template.py", line 16, in decorated_function
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/project/apps/store/views/auth.py", line 52, in login
    user = users[0]
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/queryset/base.py", line 161, in __getitem__
    _auto_dereference=self._auto_dereference, only_fields=self.only_fields)
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/base/document.py", line 709, in _from_son
    obj = cls(__auto_convert=False, _created=created, __only_fields=only_fields, **data)
  File "/home/mohammad/shopify/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongoengine/base/document.py", line 81, in __init__
    raise FieldDoesNotExist(msg)
FieldDoesNotExist: The field 'domain' does not exist on the document 'User'
```

the summery of error is when I call `first()` function the error raises and it says can't find `domain` field in `User` collection

Comment: You need to show a lot more detail here. Include the class definitions invoved and the underlying document structure as seen from the mongodb shell ( because that output gives us all the "type" information ) for a document you expect to access. Also sample code trying to access that document via mongoengine.

Comment: @BlakesSeven I just update the question !

Comment: Are you looking at the error message? It says `field 'domain' does not exist on the document 'User'"` and it **does not** exist in your class definition at all. This is not a "version problem" but you have "different data" in your two documents. The one you "cannot load" contains a field that is "not defined" in your class. Seems trivial and perhaps mongoengine "should" just ignore it when not defined. Apparently it does not. There may be configuration but the "best" bet is to add the field.

Comment: In previous version of mongoengine this error didn't rise and the domain field was in class definition and I deleted it ! and even I delete this field from document in mongodb it raises another error like this and mention a field that exists in cmdocument class definition . See the first error of question !

Comment: I did read the error. But the fix/workaround should be clear should it not? Please look at the "Changelog" activity of the release for such "gotchas". Failing any mention there then I would submit a "bug" report. But surely defining the field in your class and marking "optional" should solve the immediate problem. I personally don't think it should care. But tracking down bugs in a release like that is a "big issue". Perhaps if you did some "leg work" yourself in the report, then a "fix" might come sooner.

Comment: thank you for your care Blake! 
I found something that I could query on db but I can't get the exact element for example when I query this `User.objects(email=email)` I don't have any problem but when I want to get the first element of `QuerySet` that error rised in this case when I call `first()` func. or even getting first element by index that error rised

Comment: in reply to your second comment I have to say you're right the errors did rise for the fields that they aren't in class definition ! 
as I followed the errors and delete all mentioned fields it fixed ! 
but it's very bad bug because in my project I change the `Document` class definitions millions of time and I don't like to lost my old records !